# Form validation array not working laravel

Tags: php, jquery, validation, laravel-5.4

I have a form with variable input fields that i want to validate. So i use a wildcard but it doesn't seem to work.

The code in my view

```
@for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++)
<div>
 <label for="title[{{ $i }}]" class="control-label">Title</label>
 <input type="text" name="title[{{ $i }}]">
  @if ($errors->has('step-title'.$i))
    <span class="help-block">
      <strong>{{ $errors->first('step-title'.$i) }}</strong>
    </span>
  @endif
</div>
@endfor
```

code in my controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'title1' => 'required|alpha_dash',
  'title.*' => 'alpha_dash',
]);
```

The strange thing is that validating with **'title1'** works fine but doesn't work with **'title.*'**. why can't i use a wildcard? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the documentation to alpha_dash rule, you can notice that you can only validate dash and underscore with the rule `alpha_dash`.

> alpha_dash
>
> The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores.

The syntax `title.*` is used to validate arrays, take a look of  this. So I would recommend you to replace the asterisk with a underscore or dash before validating.